# Eclipse stuck at 99% launching to phone

Tags: android, eclipse

I launch my application through USB to my phone and suddenly Eclipse just freezes on 99%. And crashes as I try to cancel the action.

I tried allocate more memory in eclipse but didn´t make any effect.

What to do?

Comment: restart pc, eclipse is terrible sometimes. When you finish your current project move to android studio.

Comment: Wow, easier than I thought. Switching to Studio right after this project...

Comment: Ha, glad it runs now. :)

Comment: I tried to switch to android studio. Couldn't even get a sample project to compile and run, even after spending way to much time on it. Abandonned ship and went back to Eclipse.

Comment: @Niels try Intellij instead. I switched to that and haven't regretted it a second.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting PC was the answer funny enough. TIP : Dont use Eclipse